# Can any anyone help to convert multiple scalar outputs into a vector output?

Tags: matlab, vector, scalar

For a situation like this:

```
for i = 1:3
    X = 4*i
end
```

I get the following outputs

```
X =

     4


X =

     8


X =

    12
```

Can anyone help to output a vector like this:  X = [4 8 12] ?

Comment: Hi Olivier, welcome to Stack Overflow. To answer your question, that would be `X = 4*(1:3)`. You seem you just started with MATLAB, so go to the "Help" menu, chose "Product help" entry, and then "MATLAB/Getting started". MATLAB's help is quite good.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, but the use of i = 1:n is VERY crucial. Can you try again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X(3) = 0;
for i = 1:3
  X(i) = 4*i;
end
```

Comment: Zoltan, see the output obtained with :  X(3) = 0;
for i = 1:3
  X(i) = 4*i
end

X =

     4     8     0


X =

     4     8     0


X =

     4     8    12    Not exactly ?

Comment: @Olivier this *is* the answer to your question. But you can't even realize that. This is why you should [***heed the suggestion of CST-Link***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063478/can-any-anyone-help-to-convert-multiple-scalar-outputs-into-a-vector-output#comment55880221_34063478) and learn basic matlab on your own.

Comment: @Olivier This is the answer, however I can't imagine why you would do this assignment in this way. A vectorized version would be not only faster but also more readable.

Comment: Thanks guys. Still waiting for the right answer to my question.

Comment: Why don't you run that piece of code? You will see, that's correct.

Comment: ZoltánCsáti, @Olivier just missed the semicolon, and keeps seeing the value of `X` in every iteration, which confuses him. What pisses me off is that he's lacking the humility to assume that we're right. ***Why does he even ask a question then if he won't listen to the answer?***

Comment: Come on @Andras, you are going too far with humility. In fact that '4' you see there, in real world situation is NOT 4 but a function. In that way, I only simplified my question. Also, I did not miss the semicolon. I wish I could see how you are right because that is what I want and what It is why I asked because I do not know.

Comment: @Olivier this answer is the answer to your question. If it is insufficient, then maybe you didn't phrase your question right. Feel free to edit your question to make it unambiguous, then it'll be easier for people to help you. At this point there's nothing anyone will be able to add to Zoltán's answer.

Comment: Thank you guys! Both Andras Deak & Zoltan